# How do you remove a file from a subversion changelist?

Tags: svn, changelist

I had a file in a subversion changelist that I later reverted. It is now still listed in the changelist even though it has no modification. How do I get rid of this changelist?

```
$ svn status

--- Changelist 'search jsps - don't delete':
        atlassian-jira/secure/views/navigator/navigator.jsp
```

I've tried

```
svn changelist --remove --changelist search\ jsps\ -\ don\'t\ delete --depth infinity
```

and

```
svn changelist --remove --changelist "search jsps - don't delete" --depth infinity
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Changelists are separate from the regular "commit only new and marked stuff" policy. Explicitely removing the file from all changelists should work.

```
svn changelist --remove atlassian-jira/secure/views/navigator/navigator.jsp
```

To remove all files from all changelists, pass the top directory of the repository, like this:

```
svn changelist --remove --depth infinity .
```

Note the last dot, which specifies the current directory.

Comment: That's ok if the changelist only contains one file. But what to do if there are lots of files in the changelist?

Comment: @Martin Either you pass a list of files instead of one, or delete all files from all changelists. Updated the answer for the latter case.